# How to create a Facebook event using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please help me for creating a Facebook event by using Graph API. In my Android Facebook App I have created a menu login, getfriend, wallpost and create event. In which I want help on create event or source code for it.

Here is my code:

```
 public class EventRequestListener implements
    com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response) throws JSONException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        /*Log.d("Facebook-Example-Event","response.length(): " + response.length());
        Log.d("Facebook-Example-Event", "Response: " + response);*/

        mSpinner.dismiss();
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(response, null, getApplicationContext(), null);
           myIntent.putExtra("API_RESPONSE", response);
           myIntent.putExtra("METHOD", "events.create");
           startActivity(myIntent);


        JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("method","events.create");
        event.put("page_id","groupid");
        event.put("name", "App event test");
        event.put("description", "it is for testing application");
        event.put("location", "locationtest");
        event.put("start_time", "2011-05-14T10:13:00");
        event.put("end_time", "2011-05-15T10:20:00");
        event.put("privacy_type", "OPEN");
       // bundle.putString("event_info",event.toString());
        Log.d(TAG,"evento "+mFacebook.request(bundle));
        mFacebook.request("POST", bundle);



    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        // Ignore Facebook errors
    }


    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Ignore File not found errors
    }


    public void onIOException(IOException e) {
        // Ignore IO Facebook errors
    }


    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
        // Ignore Malformed URL errors
    }


    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

//main menu:

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        // Login/logout toggle
        case R.id.login:
            // Toggle the button state.
            //  If coming from login transition to logout.
            if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
                AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                asyncRunner.logout(this.getBaseContext(), new LogoutRequestListener());
            } else {
                // Toggle the button state.
                //  If coming from logout transition to login (authorize).
                mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
            }
            break;

        // Wall Post
        case R.id.wallpost: // Wall Post
            mFacebook.dialog(SampleApp.this, "stream.publish", new WallPostDialogListener());
            break;

        // Get Friend's List
        case R.id.getfriends: // Wall Post
            // Get the authenticated user's friends
            mSpinner.show();
            graph_or_fql = "graph";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "name, picture, location");
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params,
                    new FriendsRequestListener());

             //mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());
            break;

        case R.id.createvent:
                      //String data;
                //mSpinner.show();                    
                mAsyncRunner.request("me/events",new EventRequestListener());


           break;
```

Comment: People may need a specific problem description in order to help you.

Comment: in my android facebook app i have created menu login,getfriend,wallpost n create event. in which i want help on create event or src code for it.

Comment: Add these explaning comments to your question and try to keep it active, so it can get some attention Swapnil.

Comment: I wish I could help more, good luck.

Comment: We can create events by Graph API.
You can check, open Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), select POST method, add to url: me/events and fields: 
"name" = "test", "start_time" = "2012-05-14T10:13:00"
As result you get ID of new event.
Also in own app I add description and end_time.

Comment: hey thanks for comment but it didn't work for me. i did mAsyncRunner.request("me/events",name="test",start_time="2012-05-14T10:13:00","POST");

Comment: and what was the error? do you have the create_event and user_events permissions?

Comment: i have both permission. it will not give me any error but it did not return event id.